# "Input string was not in a correct format." for Convert() method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have debugged my code (below) and found out the problem is the Convert() method that converts the text from the textbox. but how i fix this problem?

i have a example of similar problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fc6b2e87-3d54-4608-b6bf-4723613333bf/).

code:

```
//METHODS
    static string RollDice (int dice)
    {
        Random roll = new Random();
        int rollOutput = roll.Next(1, dice);
        //NOTE: VERY IMPORTANT! EVERY TIME THE INPUT GOES INTO THIS
        //METHOD REMEMBER TO INCREACE IT BY ONE!
        //AND NEVER LET THE USER TO ROLL TO DICE QUICKLY ONE AFTER ANOTHER!
        string rollResult = rollOutput.ToString();
        return rollResult;
    }

    static void TwiceD20(int bonus, bool advantage)
    {
        string firstRollString = RollDice(21) + bonus;
        string secondRollString = RollDice(21) + bonus;
        int firstRoll = Convert.ToInt32(firstRollString);
        int secondRoll = Convert.ToInt32(secondRollString);

        switch(advantage)
        {
            case true:
                if (firstRoll >= secondRoll)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(firstRollString);
                }
            else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(secondRollString);
                }
                break;
            case false:
                if (firstRoll <= secondRoll)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(firstRollString);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(secondRollString);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    //BUTTONS

    private void btn1d20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Roll Result: " + RollDice(21)); 
    }

    private void btnAdv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TwiceD20(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1d20.Text), true);
    }

    private void btnDisAdv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TwiceD20(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1d20.Text), false);
    }
```

Comment: Wow... instead of correctly using Random you have insane ALL CAPS comment... Please remove it as unrelated to the question as it is not dailywtf here :)

Comment: Any reason your RollDice method returns a string and not a number?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what you need to know - you're attempting to convert something that isn't an integer into an integer. The code can't do that, so it errors. What is the value of the text box at that point?

Comment: What's the text in the text box?

Comment: Why are you converting the Roll output into a string. Make the RollDice function return an int and then if it's absolutely necessary to convert it into a string, do it only then. RollDice(21) + bonus will concatenate them together, it will not add them together as numbers.

Comment: It is hard to say what the problem is exactly but basically the value of your textboxes aren't numeric. Debug and see what the values actually are that you are trying to convert.

Comment: You should not recreate a `new Random()` and throw it away every time you call `RollDice`; that will bias your random numbers. Instead, make `RollDice` a class instance and call `new Random()` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have added a non-int into the string.  So naturally you cannot convert that to an int because the string is not just an int anymmore.

```
string firstRollString = RollDice(21) + bonus;    // This won't convert back to an int
string secondRollString = RollDice(21) + bonus;   // This won't convert back to an int
int firstRoll = Convert.ToInt32(firstRollString); 
int secondRoll = Convert.ToInt32(secondRollString);
```

Adding bonus to the string result of RollDice is simply appending the string "True" or "False" to the result of RollDice.  I suspect that you think it is adding a numerical 0 or 1.

I would do as the comments suggest and have RollDice return a number.  Then you can turn it into a string and manipulate it later as you see fit.

Or, if you don't want to return anything, just make a quick change to the order of operations.

```
int firstRoll = Convert.ToInt32(RollDice(21)); 
int secondRoll = Convert.ToInt32(RollDice(21)); 
string firstRollString = firstRoll + bonus;
string secondRollString = secondRoll + bonus;
```

But, not knowing for sure what you intend for your code to do, even that may not work for you.